# How to escape JSON reserved character in PHP

Tags: php

I want to escape  [Json reserved characters](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20characters%20are%20reserved%20in%20JSON%20and,with%20%5C%22%207%20Backslash%20is%20replaced%20with%20%5C%5C)

```
// b  Backspace
// f  Form feed
// n Newline
// r Carriage return
//  t Tab
// " Double quote
// \ Backslash
```

with

```
addcslashes($value, '\b\f\n\r\t\"\v\\')
```

`\b\f\n\r\t\"\v\\` are reserved characters , but the addcslashes treat them as normal characters. which means, it doesn't  add backslash at all. this function is truly against humanity.

### Example

`\'"test`  got `\'\"\tes\t`, it should be `\\'\"test`

what is wrong with the `addcslashes` method ? what the correct  way to do this please?

### What I tried

if use json_encode, I need to decode it in another place, otherwise, we can't display these character in html. it would be display as  encoded characters.  Currently ,we can't decode it in a another place, which needs huge modification to our API.

Comment: Why is the single-quote escaped in your example there? Please provide your sample strings as valid PHP code

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem using `json_encode()` on that string, provided you define it properly ~ https://3v4l.org/dNibT

Comment: _"I want to escape Json reserved characters"_ - what for? You are not trying to assemble JSON manually, are you? (_That_ would really be _"truly against humanity"_, as you put it.)

Comment: @Phil,  it has problems in my case. what is wrong with the method addcslashes, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dedicated [JSON functions](https://php.net/json) on a string and remove the trailing and leading quotes:

```
$json = json_encode($input, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$output = mb_substr($json, 1, -1);
```

The `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag prevents non-ASCII characters to be encoded as `\uXXXX` entities.

You'll need some sanity checks such as verifying it's a string rather than `null` or some other type.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear,  please check the  `what I tried` section.

Comment: What does that addendum mean? You want entity encoding that's identical to JSON, but it cannot be JSON? How can the receiving end determine what tools were used to create them? (I have the impression that you may referring to non-ASCII characters being encoded as `\u` entities, I'll add that to the answer).